# Tern Spartan (front rack) on Bike Friday NWT

Tags: rack, folding-bicycle, bike-friday, tern

Does anyone have experience with putting a  [Tern Spartan™ low-riding front rack](https://www.ternbicycles.com/us/gear/471/spartan-rack) on a [Bike Friday New World Tourist](https://www.bikefriday.com/folding-bikes/product/bike-friday-new-world-tourist-folding-bike)? Will it fit?

Tern Spartan front rack:

[image: From their website]

[image]

Bike Friday NWT

[image: Also from website]

[Bike Friday standard front rack](https://store.bikefriday.com/product_info.php?cPath=37&products_id=19051)

[image]

Comment: I doubt that it will work with the brakes.

Comment: @DanielRHicks concur - there ARE no brakes pictured with the rack, suggests it only for disk brakes or forks where the brake is behind the tines.

Comment: @DanielRHicks good point with the brakes! Maybe I could insert a spacer and put on the rack behind the brakes! ... could be worth a try.

Comment: @Jonas - I suspect the horizontal rod would interfere with the brake arms.

Comment: It will slightly interfere but I think to an extent that is actually not noticeable.

Comment: I think you should just call Bike Friday, they're a small and very accessible company who knows their own product inside and out. They'll likely be able to help you out one way or another with racking your NWT.

Comment: Have some bonus rep for such a quality answer.  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you ;-) I hope the answer shows up as a top result in Google for others who have the same question. After all, the Tern Spartan rack is ~60 USD cheaper than the BikeFriday front rack and fits/looks more nicely then the bulk of available 26/28 inch front racks:)

Comment: When unhooking the brake cable, do the pads hit the fork first or the rack? I'm thinking that the AliExpress copy of the dahon rack would have less problems with the brakes, but without the feature of being able to be disassembled.

Comment: @Stücke, thanks for the detailed summary. I'm looking for a front rack for my Linear Limo recumbent (with 20" wheel), and I believe this might work for me. Have you had any problems with the long spacer after this period of time?

Comment: I did not have any problems. You may also want to look into this front rack: https://de.aliexpress.com/i/4000956362402.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, a Tern Spartan Front Rack does fit on a BikeFriday New World Tourist ([and also the Tern Cargo rear rack](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/65941/39705)):
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

To prevent the rack from interfering with the V-brakes I mounted the upper end of the rack (and the fender) on a 80mm screw. Behind the fork I inserted 4x6mm spacer (the thinner in diameter the better) to mount the rack before the V-brakes (yes, the mount does interfere with the brake's cable but since the surface of the spacer is smooth I do not expect to notice anything when braking):

[image]
[image]
[image]

As of January 2020, Tern offers two versions of the Spartan front rack. 74mm and 100mm. I bought the 74mm version. When mounting the rack to my BikeFriday NWT, I felt like the rack could be slightly wider in order to being able to mount it with less force. However when measuring the rack at the height where the panniers are mounted, I measure roughly 100 mm which I find confusing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some may argue that using a 80mm screw with a margin of some 30mm from the fork to attach the rack reduces the stability of the rack and the maximum loading capacity. However, to me this does not seem to be the case considering that I will not mount very high weights to the rack. I do not know if my solution also works with disc brakes rather than V-brakes.

Comment: Excellent solution - thank you for coming back to share it, +1.    If your fix shows flexiness after a while, you could use a larger-diameter of spacer to give a wider stance.  Also, the curved profile at the rear may benefit from one of those rear caliper brake-washers that have a flat face and a curved face opposite.

Comment: The 74mm version is for Bromptons that have a narrow front hub (74mm vs 100mm for a standard hub).

Comment: I don't think so because Brompton ships with 16 inch rims whereas Tern has no bicycle with rims smaller than 20 inch. I doubt the rack fits well on a Brompton.